# CSS3: Change shape of button on hover

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I created a button:

http://jsfiddle.net/fy2zG/#&togetherjs=xaJ1VA8PBN

My css so far is:

```
.button {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

My goal is to have (only) the right side of the button turning to an arrow peak on hover. The result should be something similar like this:

[image: Arrow]

When hovering out, the button shall transit to its original shape.

Is this something that can be achieved with CSS or is jQuery needed?

Comment: my god too many people collaborating on that fiddle.. 0__0

Comment: Do you already have established code / image for the arrow shape or are you also requesting this?

Comment: @Raptus See my css code which defines the style of the button

Comment: this is the function by fiddle i guess ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Working example

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmad/fy2zG/1/)

## EDIT, now with transition

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmad/fy2zG/4/)

## EDIT, now with transition on mouseout

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmad/fy2zG/7/)

## HTML

```
<a href="#" class="button">login</a>
```

## CSS

```
.button {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
}
.button:after {
    content: " ";
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0;
    border-left-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
}
.button:hover:after {
    content: " ";
    display:block;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left-color: orange;
    border-width: 25px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Great fiddle, though I find that functionality really ugly, you might wanna put a CSS3 transition in there to give a more 'clean' functionality

Comment: Thanks all, Added CSS transition @Raptus ... I am not sure how to use collab yet!

Comment: @ahmadAlfy excellent answer! is there any way to also have a transition  back to the original shape on mouseout?

Comment: @KentMiller I tried to do it but it doesn't fade out smoothly. Will try and update the post.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy: awesome, I changed the style for my needs: http://jsfiddle.net/M9kML/  any idea how to make all three corners of the arrow round?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54522/discussion-between-ahmad-alfy-and-kent-miller).

Answer (score 0):

Can't make that with css or jQuery (unless i don't know some plugin).

Basically you must have two images. One for normal button, one for arrow shaped button. And `onNover` just change background image using background transition. But i think it will look ugly.

Comment: Well, it's sort of possible to do with just css and extra element for the arrowhead, but with limited graphical design possibilites. The different color edges will be an instant problem.

Comment: @Toni yes, i thought about that too and excluded that "possibility"

Comment: SVG could be an option, but I've never used it, and is not a common way to go about it.